# Javascript array provide all days/months between two date ranges

Tags: javascript, date, google-sheets

I'm trying to create a function that will accept three input variables (start date, end date, granularity) and will output an array with all dates in between.  The output will be either daily or monthly granularity based on the input.  For example, if I'm looking at Jan 2015 - Feb 2015:

- Monthly will be [2015-01, 2015-02]
- Daily will be [2015-01-01, 2015-01-02, 2015-01-03, ....,2015-02-27, 2015-02-28]

I've coded something based off some other posts and logically it seems like it should work to me, but for some reason when looking at daily granularity every month returns with 31 days.  The below script only looks at the daily granularity (monthly will be easier to do) - can someone take a look and see what I'm doing wrong, and if there is a more efficient way to do this?

Input format for dates are "yyyy-mm"

I realize this is probably a rookie mistake, but at least I'll learn :)

Thanks

```
function dateRange2 (startDate,endDate,granularity) {

    var dates = [];
    var d0 = startDate.split('-');
    var d1 = endDate.split('-');
    var months31 = [1,3,5,7,8,10,12];
    var months30 = [4,6,9,11];


    for (var y = d0[0]; y <= d1[0]; y++) {
        for (var m = d0[1]; m <= d1[1]; m++) {
            if (m in months31) { 
                for (var d =1;d <=31; d++) {
                    dates.push(y+"-"+m+"-"+d);
                }
            }  ///// Issue seems to be here - not switching over to next clause
            else if (m in months30) {
                for (var d =1; d <=30; d++) {
                    dates.push(y+"-"+m+"-"+d);
                }
            } else if (m=2 && y=2016) {   
                for (var d =1; d <=29; d++) {
                    dates.push(y+"-"+m+"-"+d);
                }
            } else if (m=2 && y!=2016) {   
                for (var d =1; d <=28; d++) {
                    dates.push(y+"-"+m+"-"+d);
                }
            }        
        }
    }
    return dates;
}
```

Comment: try using `.contains` instead of `.indexOf`

Answer (score 2):

instead of in operator, use indexOf as below:

```
if (months31.indexOf(m) >= 0){
}
else if (months30.index(m) >= 0){
}
```

in operator will return whether a given value is a property of object or not:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Tried this and I was getting [2016-2016-1, 2016-2016-2....,  2016-2016-29] for a few different outputs.     Even if this doesn't work I'll look this feature up now.    EDIT:
Actually, even with my original formula I get the above results if I enter faulty results (i.e. month 13), so I'll look into this a bit more

Answer (score 1):

Others have shown how to fix your code. To answer "more efficient" is difficult since you haven't provided criteria for that. But if you want robust code with separation of concerns, consider separate functions to parse date strings, format the dates and to calculate the ranges.

There are many small libraries for parsing and formatting dates that are handy if you have many different formats to accommodate, but if not then the following simple functions should suit.

If the documentation and comments are sufficient, please ask and I'll provide updates.

```js
/* Parse date string in ISO 8601 format as local
** @param {string} s - Date string like 2016-04-01
** @returns {Date} If date is invalid, returns an invalid Date
*/
function parseISODate(s) {
  var b = s.split(/\D/);
  var d = new Date(b[0], b[1]? b[1] - 1 : 0, b[2] || 1);
  return d && d.getMonth() == b[1] - 1? d : new Date(NaN);
}

/* Return an ISO 8601 formatted date string based on local time
** Only works for positive years (i.e. doesn't do -ve year)
** @param {Date} date - date object to create date string from
** @returns {string} dates string in yyyy-mm-dd format or default from
**                   Date.prototype.toString (i.e. "Invalid Date")
*/
function toISODate(date) {
  return date.getDate()? ('000' + date.getFullYear()).slice(-4) + '-' +
                         ('0' + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '-' +
                         ('0' + date.getDate()).slice(-2) : date.toString();
}

/* Generate an array of ISO 8601 formatted date strings for a
** range of dates inclusive of start and end. Either monthly
** or daily intervals (default is daily).
** @param {string} fromDate - start date in ISO 8601 format
** @param {string} toDate   - end date in ISO 8601 format
** @param {boolean} monthly - return monthly intervals 
** @returns {Array} of date strings. If either fromDate or
**                  toDate are invalid, returns undefined.
*/
function genDatesInRange(fromDate, toDate, monthly) {
  var s = parseISODate(fromDate);
  var e = parseISODate(toDate);
  var dates = [];

  // Check that dates are valid
  if (!s.getDate() || !e.getDate()) return;

  // If monthly, set start to 1st of start month and e to 1st of end month
  if (monthly) {
    s.setDate(1);
    e.setDate(1);
  }

  while (s <= e) {
    dates.push(monthly? toISODate(s).substr(0,7) : toISODate(s));
    if (monthly) {
      s.setMonth(s.getMonth() + 1);
    } else {
      s.setDate(s.getDate() + 1);
    }
  }
  return dates;
}

// Daily
console.log(genDatesInRange('2015-05-23','2015-06-03'));       // Daily
console.log(genDatesInRange('2015-09-03','2016-03-13', true)); // Monthly
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out after some trial and error - it may not be the prettiest code but it does the job... ideally I'd have added each commented line as part of a separate function.

I also noticed that each case works using four "if" arguments without requiring "else if".

```
function dateRangetest (start_month,start_year,end_month,end_year,granularity) {

var dates = [];
var d0 = [start_year,start_month];
var d1 = [end_year,end_month];

// var d0 = [2014,6]      FOR TESTING
// var d1 = [2016,4]

  switch (granularity) {
    case "Daily":
      for (var y = d0[0]; y <= d1[0]; y++) {
        if ((y == d0[0]) && (d0[0] != d1[0])) {     // if year=start_year && year != end year   ...  start from start_month and loop up to month 12
          for (var m = d0[1]; m <= 12; m++) {      
            for (var d =1;d <= monthday(m,y); d++) {
              dates.push(y+"-"+m+"-"+d)
            }
          } 
        }
        if ((y != d0[0]) && (y!= d1[0])) {         //  if year != start_year && year != end year ....  start from month 1 to month 12    - this would 2015 data in pulling Dec 2014 - April 2016
          for (var m = 1; m <= 12; m++) {      
            for (var d =1;d <= monthday(m,y); d++) {
              dates.push(y+"-"+m+"-"+d)
            }
          } 
        }
        if ((y != d0[0]) && (y == d1[0])) {       //   if year !=start_year && year = end_year   ....  start from month 1 up until end_month
          for (var m = 1; m <= d1[1]; m++) {      
            for (var d =1;d <= monthday(m,y); d++) {
              dates.push(y+"-"+m+"-"+d)
            }
          } 
        }

        if ((y == d0[0]) && (y == d1[0])) {      /// if year=start_year && year = end_year   ....  start from start_month to end_month
          for (var m = d0[1]; m <= d1[1]; m++) {      
            for (var d =1;d <= monthday(m,y); d++) {
              dates.push(y+"-"+m+"-"+d)
            }
          } 
        }
      }
      break;
    case "Monthly":
      for (var y = d0[0]; y <= d1[0]; y++) {
        if ((y == d0[0]) && (d0[0] != d1[0])) {     // if year=start_year && year != end year   ...  start from start_month and loop up to month 12
          for (var m = d0[1]; m <= 12; m++) {
            dates.push(y+"-"+m)
          }
        }
        if ((y != d0[0]) && (y!= d1[0])) {         //  if year != start_year && year != end year ....  start from month 1 to month 12    - this would 2015 data in pulling Dec 2014 - April 2016
          for (var m = 1; m <= 12; m++) {
            dates.push(y+"-"+m)
          }
        }
        if ((y != d0[0]) && (y == d1[0])) {       //   if year !=start_year && year = end_year   ....  start from month 1 up until end_month
          for (var m = 1; m <= d1[1]; m++) {
            dates.push(y+"-"+m)
          }
        }

        if ((y == d0[0]) && (y == d1[0])) {      /// if year=start_year && year = end_year   ....  start from start_month to end_month
          for (var m = d0[1]; m <= d1[1]; m++) {
            dates.push(y+"-"+m)
          }
        }
      }  
  }
  return dates
}

///  Function for Day Date Range
function monthday (month,year) {
var months31 = [1,3,5,7,8,10,12]
var months30 = [4,6,9,11]
var leapyear = [2016,2020,2024,2028,2032]

if (months31.indexOf(month) >=0){
  var result = 31}
  else if (months30.indexOf(month) >=0){
    var result = 30}
  else if (month==2 && leapyear.indexOf(year) >=0){
    var result = 29}
  else if (month==2 && year != 2016){
    var result = 28}

  return result
}
```